# When should I use ExpressJS (for backend) & jQuery (frontend) over Angular2+ (web framework) when dealing with a production PWA?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, web-frameworks

I am actually quite confused around the fundamental differences between Angular 2+ (not AngularJS), and Express.

During initial stages of learning, and some bad guidance, I always thought that Angular handled the front-end part a web app, and renders client-side (like AngularJS). Turns out (according to this link: https://hackernoon.com/reactjs-vs-angular-comparison-which-is-better-805c0b8091b1 ), Angular2+ actually renders on server-side (since, TypeScript), as well as ExpressJS renders on server-side.

Now, I've read that Angular handles routing, as well as allows for handling business logic (as well as what I understand, database connectivity with NoSQL as well as SQL databases), in one single deployment (that means, running only on instance on server), whereas, if I were to separate Angular for "frontend logic", and Express for "backend logic", I would have to deal with 2 server instances, development of APIs using Express, calling them and catering them in the Angular frontend, basically doing the same stuff twice.

Now, for a progressive web app, or PWA, made using Angular, I don't really need APIs, as I would not be catering to native applications on Android/iOS/(insert your platform of choice)/React-frontend, and hence, can I (or should I) skip using Express at all, and use Angular solely for this, given, hypothetical PWA?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Unfortunately, this is exactly the kind of question that is [off topic here](/help/on-topic), as there is no true objective reason to pick one over the other. Please remember this is not a general help forum, but specifically a site to help solve programming problems, so: take the [tour], read through what's on topic, give ["how to ask a good question"](/help/how-to-ask) a read-through, and then the next question will probably be more in line with what SO was set up for =)

Answer (score 1):

Angular is a front-end technology. Its main purpose is to generate HTML, JS and CSS for a browser. That's where Angular runs and shines.
That said, there is a project called Angular Universal that allows you to run Angular on the server side. The purpose of that project is to pre-render HTML from the server for SEO and speed purposes.

Express on the other end is back-end only. You can use Express to connect to a database and return data to a front-end. Angular cannot to do that. So it's really not Angular vs Express but rather Angular + Express that you need to build a PWA.